# An immature thought about constructing an continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $Q=\{r_n|n=1,2,\cdots\}$ be a list of all rational numbers , and $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(r_n-\frac{1}{2^n},r_n+\frac{1}{2^n})$.Given $g(x)=\inf_{y\notin U}{|x-y|}$.Prove $g(x)$  is a continuous function.

Here's my try : Let $U_N=\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}(r_n-\frac{1}{2^n},r_n+\frac{1}{2^n}) $ and $g_N(x)=\inf_{y\notin U_N}{|x-y|}$.Since $U_N\subset U_{N+1}$,we have $g_{N+1}(x)\geq g_N(x)$,and
if we can prove $$ g_{N+1}(x)- g_N(x) \leq \frac{1}{2^N} $$ We can get when $M$, $N$ are both
sufficiently large, $|g_{M}(x)- g_N(x)|$ can be arbitary small. So $g_N(x)\rightrightarrows g_0(x)$. Since all $g_N(x)$ is continuous , $g_0(x)$ is continuous.

But today when I reflected on this problem, I noticed $g_0(x)$ is not trivially equal to $g(x)$.So did I come to a dead end?Can someone provide a detailed proof to this problem?

Comment: Not a detailed proof, but a hint: given a subset $U\subsetneq\mathbb R$, the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,~f(x)=\inf_{y\not\in U}\vert x-y\vert$ is continuous. You don't need the specific definition of $U$ for this.

Comment: More explicitly $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|$ for the function defined in above comment.